# How do I view/edit Java source code from APKs on an Android phone?

Tags: applications, apk

As an Android developer, I often need to browse Java source code of APKs.

Is there any way or tool that lets me view Java source codes *inside of `.apk` files* and be able to edit them on the phone? I know of [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/), but it's for PC, not for mobile.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that *is there an app for X* questions are off-topic here (see our [help/on-topic]). I took the freedom to re-phrase it to avoid it being closed (oh, and geff did the same in parallel), so please don't wonder about that :) // Please [edit] it as well and include if you're talking about editing plain `.java` files, or want to look into compiled `.apk` files.

Comment: @Izzy: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit it.

Comment: Question remains: separate `.java` files *for* `.apk` – or Java code from inside compiled `.apk` files? To make it more obvious: if the `.java` files are directly accessible with any file browser, any editor could be used (and there are really good ones around for devs). If you're talking about stuff *inside `.apk` files*, that wouldn't do as you first had to "get them out of the `.apk`".

Comment: @Izzy: I mean java code from inside compiled apk file.

Comment: OK, then I have to pass. Editing inside `.apk` files is not my expertise.